# SharePoint 2007 Word Document Conversion Very Slow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I'm calling the SharePoint API (SPFile.Convert - MOSS 2007) to convert a docx to html with the out-of-the-box Word to HTML converter.

According to the SharePoint logs, the Launcher Service tries to start the DocXPageConverter.exe process immediately.  Then, around 7 minutes later the logs report that the process has been successfully created.

I see DocXPageConverter.exe briefly appear in task manager right at the end of this time.  So, the conversion appears to run quickly once the process has started.

What's causing this long delay?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Aspose.Words for SharePoint that can (among other things) convert DOCX to HTML. It does not use the converter engine of MOSS and might work faster than what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I have looked at Aspose before, but I really need to get the out-of-the-box SharePoint conversion running faster.

Answer (score 0):

In Central Administration, go to Application Management > Configure Document Conversions. In this section there is a Conversion Schedule. Try setting the schedule to Every 1 Minute. I've tried this but my document conversion is still shockingly slow - hopefully you will get more benefit though :)

Comment: Thanks James, but it's set to one minute already. At first, the conversions took less than a minute, but they have gradually slowed down over the months.